# nwjs-nodejs- encrypt and decrypt img file (jpg) and use the decrypted data to an img element

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, fs, nwjs

I developed a desktop application with nwjs (nodejs / html / css ), now i want to put the app for the production so i need to prevent stealing my assets (my images are very valuables), nwjs provide a tool to compile (encrypt) the js files but not the asset so i thought about encrypting my assets with a js then encrypt the js with nwjs tool, i am not very familiare with node modules and dealing with files in js so i struggled with this task !
This code is what i tried to do but i did not reach my goal ?

- encrypt

  ```
  let crypto;
  try {
      crypto = require('crypto');
  } catch (err) {
      console.log('crypto support is disabled!');
  }
  var algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr',
          password = 'secret';
  var fs = require('fs');
  var r;

  // encrypt content
  var encrypt = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password);
  // decrypt content
  var decrypt = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, password);

  // write file
  var w;
  var path = require('path');
  var dirPath = './Files/';  //directory path
  var fileType = '.' + 'jpg'; //file extension
  var files = [];
  fs2.readdir(dirPath, function (err, list) {
      if (err) throw err;
      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
          if (path.extname(list[i]) === fileType) {
              r = fs.createReadStream('Files/' + list[i]);
              w = fs.createWriteStream('encFiles/' + list[i].replace('.jpg', ''));
              console.log(list[i]); //print the file
              // start pipe
              r.pipe(encrypt).pipe(w);
          }
      }
  });
  ```
- decrypt

  ```
      'use strict';
  var crypt = require('crypto'),
          algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr',
          password = 'secret';

  var fs = require('fs');
  var zlib = require('zlib');
  var toArray = require('stream-to-array');

  // input file
  var r = fs.createReadStream('./encFiles/an example file'); 
  // decrypt content
  var decrypt = crypt.createDecipher(algorithm, password);

  //b64 module so i could put the base64 data to img html element
  const B64 = require('b64');

  const encoder = new B64.Encoder();

  // start pipe
  var stream = r.pipe(decrypt);

  var d = stream.pipe(encoder);
  d.pipe(process.stdout);

  var data;
  toArray(stream, function(err, arr) {
      console.log(err,arr);
      data = Buffer.concat(arr);
      console.log(data);
  });
  console.log(data);
  ```

thank you for giving me comments on the code or other IDEAS

Comment: If you display the image in a canvas or image tag they can be saved. It won't matter that you encrypted them in transit. I've seen people render individual pixels to avoid this. Doing so still allows a user to take a screenshot. If you want a full proof solution, perhaps a custom encoding (or encryption) decode it to an image in the browser. If the browser window looses focus overlay the images until it regains focus. The same thing on mouse over.

Comment: I suggest you look at the NodeJS encryption code in [this repository](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples) for an example of secure encryption.

Comment: @N-ate i know that i won't provide a full security on my images but at least i won't put them in clear so anyone could open my files and copy-past the images !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was so simple, I used the [**nw-js code protection feature**](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/Protect%20JavaScript%20Source%20Code/) to protected the script in which I decrypt the assets (images in my case) (this script contains the key of decryption), so you could implement the encryption/decryption with any method you want and protect the decryption script which is going to be shipped with you product (in my case the **desktop app**).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are building a desktop app, you may want to look at cryptojs for this. I would still strongly suggest that you watermark images and hide them when your application looses focus. Even with that, screenshots can be taken without leaving your application.